# Change Input Value on Radio Change

Tags: jquery, html

I have 2 product and I want to append the product name with the gender when the user selects their gender. I have almost got it working but just not quite there yet. The gender sometimes duplicates and if you change from dudes to chicks then it keeps both. I know that there is an elegant solution but I just cant find it. Any help would be much appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/rbh9qzwo/1/

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="name" value="Graphics Sock" required>Graphics
    <input type="radio" name="name" value="Pattern Sock" required>Patterns</br>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Dudes" required>Dudes
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Chicks" required>Chicks
</form>

$('input:radio[name="gender"]').each(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Dudes') {
        $('input:radio[name="name"]').val($('input:radio[name="name"]').val() + 'Dudes');
    }

    if ($(this).val() == 'Chicks') {
        $('input:radio[name="name"]').val($('input:radio[name="name"]').val() + 'Chicks');
    }

});
```

Comment: Can you clearly articulate your goal? I don't see you listening to any click event.

Answer (score 0):

Use a data attribute to save the original value, like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="product" value="product1" data-original="product1">
```

Then, in your javascript, just replace value = value + gendervalue with value = data-original1 + gendervalue.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for something like:

```
$(function() {
    $(':radio').on('change', function() {
        var gender = $(':radio[name=gender]:checked').val();
        gender = gender || '';
        $(':radio[name=name]:checked').val( function() {
            return $(this).attr('value') + gender;
        });
    });
});
```

```js
$(function() {
    $(':radio').on('change', function() {
        var gender = $(':radio[name=gender]:checked').val();
        gender = gender || '';
        $(':radio[name=name]:checked').val( function() {
            return $(this).attr('value') + gender;
        });
        alert( $(':radio[name=name]:checked').val() );
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="name" value="Graphics Sock" required>Graphics
    <input type="radio" name="name" value="Pattern Sock" required>Patterns<br>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Dudes" required>Dudes
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Chicks" required>Chicks
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="name" value="Graphics Sock" data-original = "Graphics Sock" required>Graphics
    <input type="radio" name="name" value="Pattern Sock" data-original = "Pattern Sock" required>Patterns</br>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Dudes" required>Dudes
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Chicks" required>Chicks
</form>

<script>


$('input:radio[name="gender"]').on("click",function () {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Dudes') {
        $('input:radio[name="name"]').each(function(){$(this).val($(this).attr("data-original") + ' Dudes'); } ) 
    }

    if ($(this).val() == 'Chicks') {
        $('input:radio[name="name"]').each(function(){$(this).val($(this).attr("data-original") + ' Chicks');})      
    }
});
</script>
```